# How to use DZT gem inside the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openseadragon

I have a feeling my question might have a very easy answer. I am working on a Rails 6.1 solution that uses openseadragon to view, zoom and annotate large images. The solution requires the uploaded file to be 'tiled' to a DZI format. I found the 'dzt' gem that should do the trick.
I added the gem to the gem file and ran "bundle install".

The instructions (https://github.com/dblock/dzt) show:

```
dzt slice image.jpg --output tiles
```

This works fine from the command line, the 'tiles' folder is created etc. But when I try to run the command from inside a model or the ruby IRB. I get this error:

```
SyntaxError ((irb):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting do or '{' or '(') dzt slice image.jpg --output tiles
```

I have tried adding require "dzt" to the model class but it does not seem to make a difference. Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could you include the code that you are executing in IRB that causes the error to be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to put the command in back-ticks and it works.

```
`dzt slice image.jpg --output tiles`
```